# Using angular-material-design in Angular 4 app (+ Angular CLI)

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular-cli, bootstrap-material-design

How to use [bootstrap-material-design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design) in Angular 4 app (*with Angular CLI*)?

I just added css file in my `styles.css` like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css";
```

I can access bootstrap-material-design classes but some elements like inputs don't work like it should.

I think I have to add in `.angular-cli.json` file the `jQuery` and `bootstrap-material-design` scripts but that didn't work either.

What is the correct way?

From Docs, I need to initialize the material javascript by adding the following javascript to your site, but I can't.

```
$.material.init()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Nano for his answer which helps me.

So, I added my styles and scripts like this in angular-cli.json:

```
    "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css",
        "styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min.js"
    ]
```

Then, we have to init bootstrap-material-design.
That's important to do it after the context initialisation. So, in a ngOnInit() was perfect for me.
I did that in my app.component.ts like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare let jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        // Init bootstrap-material-design
        jQuery.material.init();
    }
}
```

And it works like I want. Inputs are normal.

Comment: For bootstrap 4 they have asked to add $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign();

Answer (score 1):

One you have installed the library by running

```
npm install --save bootstrap-material-design
```

you should be able to link all the css and js files to your project.

To do that you should link such files in your `angular-cli.json` file.

The arrays to fill in the json are respectively `styles` for the css and `scripts` for the js.

```
  "styles": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/sass/bootstrap-material-design.scss"
    ...
  ]

  ...

  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scripts/index.js"
  ]
```

Hope this works for you!

EDIT:

If you wish to use Material Design more easily you can try this one:

> https://github.com/angular/material2

It is also the official one, well integrated with the framework.

Comment: Hi Nano! thank you for your answer. Where did you put this call: $.material.init()? And why import /scripts/index.js and not /dist/js/material.js?

Comment: You can call it from the index.html page in a script tag!

Comment: You import /scripts/index.js because it is the development version and not the compiled one.